# A few (basic) questions from datacamp's intro to dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

A couple of probably basic questions from  DataCamp's intro to dplyr course:

Why does:

```
hflights %>% 
  group_by(UniqueCarrier,Dest) %>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rank=rank(n)) %>%
  filter(rank==1)
```

Generate a different answer than:

```
 hflights %>% 
      group_by(UniqueCarrier, Dest) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rank = rank(desc(n))) %>%
      filter(rank == 1)
```

The only difference is the rank order, but shouldn't filter be agnostic to the order in which items are ranked?

Second, Why does mean(ArrDelay>0) generate the proportion of flights with ArrDelay>0 in the below case?  Shouldn't it just give you the average delay of all flights that have a positive delay?

```
hflights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ArrDelay)) %>%
  group_by(UniqueCarrier) %>%
  summarize(p_delay=mean(ArrDelay>0)) %>%
  mutate(rank=rank(p_delay)) %>%
  arrange(rank)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your first question but for the second: `ArrDelay>0` creates a logical vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` and applying `mean()` to that vector coerces the logical vector to `1`s and `0`s and then takes the mean of it. I think what you expect is something like `mean(ArrDelay[ArrDelay>0])`

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the first question. Why would you expect the same results? Have a look at what `desc` actually does, e.g. `desc(1:3)`. Clearly the ranks should be different.

```
rank(1:3)
## [1] 1 2 3
rank(desc(1:3))
## [1] 3 2 1
```

For your second question: `ArrDelay > 0` is a logical. When you take the mean of a logical, it converts it to numeric first (TRUE -> 1, FALSE -> 0). Then it takes the mean, which is the proportion of TRUEs. To get the mean of all delays with positive delay, use

```
hflights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ArrDelay)) %>%
  group_by(UniqueCarrier) %>%
  summarize(p_delay=mean(ArrDelay[ArrDelay>0])) %>%
  mutate(rank=rank(p_delay)) %>%
  arrange(rank)
```